# Angular Unknown Provider [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider

Tags: angularjs, heroku

It's working locally (localhost:3000) but not when I deploy to heroku 
( https://get-started.herokuapp.com/ ). I get a jquery error saying

```
[$injector:unpr] Unknown provider
```

this is the main

```
function config($locationProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
  'ngInject';

  $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
}
```

home

```
function config($stateProvider) {
  'ngInject';

  $stateProvider
  .state('home', {
    url: '/',
    template: '<home></home>'
  });
}
```

about

```
function config($stateProvider) {
  'ngInject';

  $stateProvider
  .state('about', {
    url: '/about',
    template: '<about></about>'
  });
}
```

Comment: Could you please share your module file code as well as index/html code.

Comment: Can you ensure that the use of `ngInject` is justified, and the appropriate dependencies are being resolved?

Answer (score 0):

It's happen because of minification. When you minify, that $scope variable may be called something totally different, like a, and Angular won't know what that means -- it uses the strings to solve that issue

You need smth like this :

```
app.controller('HeadMenuController', ['$scope', '$log',
    function($scope, $log){...}
]);
```

This way, Angular can still match the dependencies up

Comment: OP is using `ng-annotate`, which already takes care of the dependency injection. `'ngInject';` denotes it.

Comment: Thank you! I think the problem is with config and ui-router, not the controllers. Is there a way to use ui-router without .config?